# scrollIntoView not Smooth in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, smooth-scrolling, js-scrollintoview

I'm using vanilla JS to have a button smoothly scroll down to an div element (target the id)

I have this as my code:

```
this.myButton.addEventListener("click",load_section);
function load_section() {  
        document.querySelector('#myDiv').scrollIntoView({ block: 'end',  behavior: 'smooth' });  
    }
```

In all other browsers, this scrolls to the section smoothly. In Edge, it just jumps to it. What do I need to change to make it scroll smoothly down to the section

Comment: Afaik options object is not supported in Edge.

Comment: Thanks, just saw that, what can I do to initiate a smooth scrolling for Edge?

Answer (score 2):

For a more comprehensive list of methods for smooth scrolling, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689657/9513184).

---

To scroll to a certain position in an exact amount of time, [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) can be put to use, calculating the appropriate current position each time. To scroll to an element, just set the y-position to `element.offsetTop`.

```js
/*
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```

Demo:

```js
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}

document.getElementById("toElement").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 500 /* milliseconds */);
});
document.getElementById("backToTop").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  scrollToSmoothly(0, 500);
});
```

```html
<button id="toElement">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 1000px 0px; text-align: center;">Div element
  <button id="backToTop">Scroll back to top</button>
</div>
```

The [SmoothScroll.js library](https://github.com/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll) can also be used, which supports scrolling to an element on the page in addition to more complex features such as smooth scrolling both vertically and horizontally, scrolling inside other container elements, different easing behaviors, scrolling relatively from the current position, and more.

```js
smoothScroll({toElement: document.getElementById('elementId'), duration: 500});
```

```js
document.getElementById("toElement").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  smoothScroll({toElement: document.querySelector('div'), duration: 500});
});
document.getElementById("backToTop").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  smoothScroll({yPos: 'start', duration: 500});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll@1.2.0/src/smoothscroll.min.js" integrity="sha384-UdJHYJK9eDBy7vML0TvJGlCpvrJhCuOPGTc7tHbA+jHEgCgjWpPbmMvmd/2bzdXU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="toElement">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 1000px 0px; text-align: center;">Div element
  <button id="backToTop">Scroll back to top</button>
</div>
```